# Cannot use Bluetooth on Laptop

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Clevo N850HK1 laptop.

I just (don't really use it) found out that I cannot enable/use bluetooth. This is what I get from Bluetooth settings when I try to enable it.

[image: Bluetooth is disabled.]

The laptop does not have any bluetooth hardware switches. (I double checked.)

To help with debugging this here are some more information from the terminal:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.     RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1558:850a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b59e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
$ lsmod | grep blue
bluetooth             557056  14 btrtl,hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm,btusb
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
$ dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.177482] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.689122] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[    2.748370] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    2.748380] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.748382] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.748383] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.748386] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.753562] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[    2.754643] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    2.754660] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    2.754660] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    2.754661] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    2.754661] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    2.754662] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    2.756845] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-12-16.sfi failed with error -2
[    2.756847] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    2.757664] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[    2.758691] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    2.758704] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    2.758704] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    2.758704] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    2.758704] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    2.758705] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    2.758710] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-12-16.sfi failed with error -2
[    2.758711] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    3.003906] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.003907] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.003907] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    3.003908] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    3.003908] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    3.003909] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.003925] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    3.003932] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    3.003932] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    3.003933] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    3.126669] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[    3.129488] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    3.129489] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    3.129489] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    3.129489] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    3.129490] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    3.129491] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.129515] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-12-16.sfi failed with error -2
[    3.129516] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file  (-2)
[    3.193592] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.193601] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.214247] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.361476.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.454217] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.454218] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.454220] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Lastly my system is a fully upgraded Ubuntu 16.04.2

```
$ uname -r
4.8.0-41-generic
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Any ideas on what I have to do to enable bluetooth?

Comment: Have you installed `bluetooth` and `bluez`? Do `apt-cache policy blue*` to find out.

Comment: What have you done to locate/install the missing Intel firmware, ibt-12-16.sfi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need firmware for this device. It can be installed this way:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
```

This will install the firmware from the `yakkety` release. The `xenial` package has not been updated yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw there's a newer package [there](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.163_all.deb). Should I install it instead?

Comment: This is for 17.04. I do not recommend installing it. You actually need one file.